# Windows 8 for Visual Studio development

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio

I assume people use Windows 8 for Visual Studio development, mainly web applications in my case. I have been using Windows 7 for the past few years, and normally I like to keep up to date with the OS version. However I have a laptop running Windows 8, and I find the Metro UI and fullscreen thing for some applications extremely frustrating.

Do you have any opinions on using Windows 8 for development? Is it recommended? I would like to switch, but the worst thing that I would want is having to revert back as I find it too frustrating.

Comment: Visual studio still works on Windows 8 your question is unclear...Any application that works on Windows 7 would work on Windows 8

Comment: if you dont like windows 8 use windows 7. it will be supported with security updates for many years to come.

Comment: I have used VS in both W7 and W8... I really don't see what your issue is! Seems like you're here just to whine (sorry!).

Comment: @DaveRook I understand that this might be an opinion-based question - What can I do to improve on this question, considering it was closed?  Or should I just remove it?

Comment: Not really, as I don't know what you're trying to ask...

Comment: @DaveRook I was trying to see given that this is used a lot by programmers what is there experience in using Windows 8 for development.  I have a Win8 license for all the computers in the office, however wanted to know if it is worthwhile doing the upgrade for development.  Looking at it now, I know it is a very opinion-based question and wouldn't fit in this forums model.  I've been blocked from asking any further questions, I'm assuming due to this - Is there anything I can do?  Ill make sure not to ask such questions in the future.

Comment: @KarlCassar, Apparently you have to 'work it off' - I found nothing more than that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [StartIsBack](http://startisback.com/) or a different Startmenu program and you can work like in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just afraid with the Metro interface nothing else. Just use the desktop version of Win 8 and you are good to do any development like WEB/Windows. Even you can read about Metro style application development and go for it.

I used the Visual Studio with Win 8 and Win 7 and both have no difference when using it. There is no difference in developing a Web/windows app on Win 8. And about recommending for development then obviously Win 8 is the prefer one as it has many new Metro  style apps which encouraging the devs to work with it.